# Count Cells in Column If Range Changes

Tags: excel

I have found this place immensely helpful in the past, so I figured I'd ask a question since I haven't been able to find it elsewhere or through a search.  I've seen similar results but nothing that I believe I can modify for my needs... perhaps I'm not searching for the right thing.  Here goes...

```
01    JAN    100
02    FEB    150
03    MAR    125
04    APR    200
05    MAY    120
06    JUN    210
07    JUL    175
08    AUG    100
09    SEP    150
10    OCT    225
11    NOV    125
12    DEC    250
```

I am trying to count the numbers in column three so that I can get a total from January through line 12, which in this case is December.  This in itself is rather easy; even I can figure that one out.  However, there are times when this table looks like this below, in which case I would only need to count from Jan through April.

```
01    MAY    120
02    JUN    210
03    JUL    175
04    AUG    100
05    SEP    150
06    OCT    225
07    NOV    125
08    DEC    250
09    JAN    100
10    FEB    150
11    MAR    125
12    APR    200
```

How can I set up a formula so that I can always get a count from January (wherever it may fall) through line 12, no matter what month falls on line 12?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table as you give it is in A1:C12:

`=SUM(C12:INDEX(C1:C12,MATCH("JAN",B1:B12,0)))`

Regards

Comment: OK, almost snap!.....at least I put C12 at the other end for a bit of variety......

Comment: :-) To be fair, that is the most logical position as well. My version is "playing" a bit with syntax!

Answer (score 1):

If months are in `B1:B12` and amounts in `C1:C12` try this formula to get a sum beginning at `JAN`

`=SUM(INDEX(C1:C12,MATCH("Jan",B1:B12,0)):C12)`

`MATCH` finds the row which contains Jan, `INDEX` then gives you the corresponding cell in column C and you get a sum from there until C12